# Datepicker shows under dialog box android

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to open a Date and Time picker in a dialog box. I'm using the plugin SingleDateandTimePickerDialog. 
My dialog is showing well, and when I'm clicking on the date field, datepicker is displayed under my dialog box... So I can't use it.

Did I miss something ?

Here my DialogHolder.java :

```
public ClientDialogHolder(View view) {
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    final Context context = view.getContext();
    DateDialog.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    new SingleDateAndTimePickerDialog.Builder(context)
                            .title(context.getString(R.string.starting_hour))
                            .curved().build().setListener(new SingleDateAndTimePickerDialog.Listener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSelected(Date date) {
                            DateDialog.setText(DateUtil.shortDateTimeString(date.getTime()));

                        }
                    }).display();
                }
            });

    Date now = new Date();
    //updateHeure(now);

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share some screenshot for the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because the datepicker dialog is visible only when I cancel the ClientDialog box. So, it is not very relevant

Answer (score 0):

Are you opening in an activity,fragment or inside any dialog box.
Perhaps you are using in Dialog Box.
Then you must specify the view where you need to open this datepicker.
Provide Dialog object while finding the view pf date picker.